# VelocityTracker causes crash on Android 4.4

Tags: android, crash, android-4.4-kitkat

In my app I have a custom implementation of a drawer layout. It works fine on Android 2.3 & 4.0.4 but on Android 4.4 it crashes almost every time I open or close the drawer.
Here is the error log :

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839): Process: com.andryr.launcher, PID: 9839
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already in the pool!
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at android.util.Pools$SimplePool.release(Pools.java:112)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at android.util.Pools$SynchronizedPool.release(Pools.java:161)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at android.view.VelocityTracker.recycle(VelocityTracker.java:85)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at com.andryr.widget.DrawerLayout.onTouchEvent(DrawerLayout.java:131)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7706)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2210)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1945)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2068)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1515)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2458)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2016)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7886)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3947)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3826)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3392)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3442)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3411)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3518)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3419)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3575)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3392)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3442)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3411)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3419)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3392)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5532)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5512)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5483)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5612)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9839):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
```

and here is my code :

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
{
    if(!mInterceptTouchEvent)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
            && ((ev.getX() < ViewConfiguration.get(getContext())
                    .getScaledEdgeSlop() && !mExpanded) || (ev.getX() > getWidth()
                    - ViewConfiguration.get(getContext())
                            .getScaledEdgeSlop())
                    && mExpanded))
    {
        if (mVelocityTracker == null)
            mVelocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
        else
            mVelocityTracker.clear();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
{
    if(!mInterceptTouchEvent)
    {
        return false;
    }
    mLastMotionX = ev.getX();
    if (mVelocityTracker == null)
        return false;
    switch (ev.getAction())
    {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        mVelocityTracker.addMovement(ev);
        mVelocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(1000);
        mVelocity = mVelocityTracker.getXVelocity();
        // ViewHelper.setTranslationX(mDrawerLayout,
        // -mDrawerLayout.getWidth()
        // + mLastMotionX);
        // ViewHelper.setTranslationX(mRootView, mLastMotionX);
        mPosition = (int) (-mDrawerLayout.getWidth() + mLastMotionX);
        requestLayout();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

        if (Math.abs(mVelocity) > ViewConfiguration.get(getContext())
                .getScaledMinimumFlingVelocity()
                && Math.abs(mVelocity) < ViewConfiguration
                        .get(getContext()).getScaledMaximumFlingVelocity())
        {
            if (mVelocity > 0)
            {
                openDrawer();

            } else
            {
                closeDrawer();

            }
        } else
        {
            if (mLastMotionX > getWidth() / 2)
            {
                openDrawer();

            } else
            {
                closeDrawer();

            }
        }

        mVelocityTracker.recycle();
        return false;

    }
    return true;
}
```

line 131 is :

```
    mVelocityTracker.recycle();
```

I don't understand why is this happening.

Comment: Did you resolve the issue? even i am getting the same error while recycling the velocitytracker object.

Comment: mVelocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(1000); is an expensive opperation.  You should consider moving this to the ACTION_UP and set default MIN_VELOCITY if velocityTracker is null.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I had to set my velocitytracker to null after recycling it to make it work porperly

Comment: not setting the VelocityTracker to null after recycling it causes crash because on the second time you use use the VelocityTracker you will recycle it a second time (recycling the same VT twice). I think (but i am not sure) an other solution would be to call VelocityTracker.clear() instead of VelocityTracker.recycle()

Comment: For me, setting it to null didn't work. It may be a better option to call clear() instead, like @andryr pointed out.

Comment: calling VelocityTracker.clear() does not reuses the velocityTracker object. It simply resets the velocity tracker back to its initial state, hence resulting in creation of new object for every scroll. This causes the GC to collect often in my application, which pauses the application for few milli seconds. Is there any other work around for this?

Comment: Worked for me. I had custom implementation of touches in my view and forgot to nullify velocityTracker object after `recycle()`. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

As metioned in the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/movement.html), you have to call `velocityTracker.clear()` if you want to use it again.

Use `velocityTracker.recycle()` if you will not use the object again- to free up resources. Do this when your activity is being destroyed.

(That's why the accepted answer by @andryr works. You are creating a new one)

Comment: Almost every statement in your answer is wrong:
velocityTracker was cleared on second down event in original post.
VelocityTracker should be recycled as soon as it's not needed anymore, in most cases it should happen on ACTION_UP or ACTION_CANCEL, not on activity destroy. Exactly this is done in example which you mentioned. And one more quote from the docs: "You should generally only maintain an active object while tracking a movement" (see VelocityTracker.obtain())
`VelocityTracker.obtain()` doesn't create new object usually, it returns one from the pool.