# Which component can I use in Android Studio for the purpose of creating a touchpad?

Tags: java, android, android-view, custom-view

I've been searching for a View/Component in Android Studio that I could use for creating a touchpad. I need the ability to track mouse movements, so that I use that information on the server side to handle it and emulate mouse movements.

What would be the best fit for that purpose?

Comment: Did you mean scrollview?

Comment: What is the exact use case? What do you want it for?

Comment: I try to write bluetooth touchpad for android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Shishdem's answer didn't satisfy me. What I basically was trying to achieve is to make a prototype of a touchpad for a school project. [`ScrollView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) contains elements that are to be scrolled within, and I needed to track finger movements information that is suitable to be handled for moving cursor on PC by my server application.

I found solution here: [Track touch and pointer movements](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/movement#java)

I needed to create an [`android.view.VelocityTracker`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/VelocityTracker) and track touch velocity to further send that data to my PC server and simulate mouse movements via [`java.awt.Robot`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) within [`onTouchEvent`](https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/touch). The component could be anything, a `Button` in my case.

Here's the working code for the class that handles touch event of a touchpad view:

```java
private VelocityTracker mVelocityTracker = null;
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int index = event.getActionIndex();
    int action = event.getActionMasked();
    int pointerId = event.getPointerId(index);

    switch(action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if(mVelocityTracker == null) {
                mVelocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
            }
            else {
                mVelocityTracker.clear();
            }

            mVelocityTracker.addMovement(event);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            mVelocityTracker.addMovement(event);
            mVelocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(1000);

            // Log velocity of pixels per second
            // Those values can be used to be sent to the server
            Log.d("Velocity", "X velocity: " + mVelocityTracker.getXVelocity(pointerId));
            Log.d("Velocity", "Y velocity: " + mVelocityTracker.getYVelocity(pointerId));

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            mVelocityTracker.recycle();
            mVelocityTracker = null;
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

### In case of crash

Note that in the example of the link above there isn't this line:

```java
mVelocityTracker.recycle();
mVelocityTracker = null; // this line
```

But in my case, if I didn't assign `mVelocityTracker` to `null` every recycle, it would crash with the following errors:

```
2021-10-05 09:30:21.711 4385-4385/com.example.javaapp E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
2021-10-05 09:30:21.711 4385-4385/com.example.javaapp E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
2021-10-05 09:30:21.713 4385-4385/com.example.javaapp E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already in the pool!
        at android.util.Pools$SimplePool.release(Pools.java:120)
        at android.util.Pools$SynchronizedPool.release(Pools.java:179)
        at android.view.VelocityTracker.recycle(VelocityTracker.java:87)
```

More on that issue: [VelocityTracker causes crash on Android 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26074907/velocitytracker-causes-crash-on-android-4-4)

Answer (score 1):

That would be a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) or a [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html).